# Logging in a user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble with logging users in, everything appears to be in the right place, I get no errors in the log, but users fail to log in, I am using the correct credentials that are in my database.

Please note I have a different set up to the normal one:

- My table is called test_users
- My model sits in a separate namespace called Test

Here's my code:

In config>auth I have set:

```
'model' => '\Test\User',


'table' => 'test_users',
```

Here is how I call the Auth:

```
public function logIn()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $credentials = array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']);

    $input['remember-me'] = isset($input['remember-me']) ? true : false;

    if(Auth::attempt($credentials, $input['remember-me']))
    {
        $this->output['message'] = 'ok';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->output['message'] = 'fail';
    }

    return $this->output;
}
```

Here's my model:

```
<?php namespace Test;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'test_users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password');

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Auth::attempt checks for a hashed password. It appears you might be trying to set them with plaintext. Try setting your passwords with Hash::make('password') if you aren't already.